# Delete Records From Database Using jQuery

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I want to add a delete button to this table, to delete the query from Database. I have the Ajax and PHP codes here :

```
<?php
        require_once 'dbconfig.php';

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
        $stmt->execute();
  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   ?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['server']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['reference']; ?></td>
   <td align="center"><a id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="delete-link" href="#" title="Delete">
   <img src="images/delete.png" width="20px" />
            </a></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
  }
  ?>
```

the ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 /* Data Delete Starts Here */
 $(".delete-link").click(function()
 {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var del_id = id;
  var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
  if(confirm('Sure to Delete ID no = ' +del_id))
  {
   $.post('delete.php', {'del_id':del_id}, function(data)
   {
    parent.fadeOut('slow');
   });
  }
  return false;
 });
 /* Data Delete Ends Here */

});
```

delete.php :

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

if($_POST['del_id'])
{
 $id = $_POST['del_id'];
 $stmt=$db_con->prepare("DELETE FROM test WHERE id=:id");
 $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
 $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

The row selected doesn't seem to get DELETED in the DB ... i have no error too.

Comment: data: {id:id}, pass data like that . Please

Comment: hey , sorry but I didn't understand ... can you be more explicit ?

Answer (score 0):

You had pass data incorrectly . Please try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('table#delTable td a.delete').click(function()
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?"))
        {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data = 'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "view.php",
                   data: {id:id},
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: it still doesnt delete it from the database :/

Comment: have you seen post request in  console ?

Comment: Simply confirm the id that have you got id value or not.

Comment: the console doesnt give any info its just /view.php . Is the code right before everything ? I really think something is missing .. like is my link <a> correct ? doesn't need any href ? and is my DELETE query placed well ?

Comment: well I really don't know how to do that, i am new to basically everything here...

Comment: I edited my codes, they look cleaner now... though I still have the same problem, nothing is deleted from DB